# matpower implemention data from electrical transmission line

Tags: matpower

Newton's method power flow (power balance, polar) did not converge in 1000 iterations.

I implement data from electrical transmission line from a city. I finished implementing all the data but when I do a runopf it tells me that newton raphson's method does not converge, I tried several things but nothing works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.